# Does a norm ball around a real matrix contain all possible pairs of complex spectrum?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

We consider the normed vector space $(M_n(\mathbb R), \|\cdot\|_F)$, i.e., real matrices with Frobenius norm. Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a diagonalizable matrix and have all eigenvalues to be real. Let $B_A(\varepsilon)$ denote the open norm ball with radius $\varepsilon > 0$, i.e., 
\begin{align*}
B_A(\varepsilon) =\{ E \in M_n(\mathbb R): \|A-E\|_F < \varepsilon\}.
\end{align*}
We know the complex eigenvalues of a real matrix must be conjugate pairs. My question is: for any combination of real or complex conjugate pairs of eigenvalues, is there always a matrix $E \in B_A(\varepsilon)$ has the spectrum with the same number of real and complex conjugate pairs. To be more clear, let $n = 2k$ be even, I would like to know whether there are always matrices in the norm ball such that have eigenvalues with $1$ complex conjugate pair, $2$ pairs, and so on until $k$ pairs of conjugate eigenvalues.

Comment: If the eigenvalues of $A$ are real and distinct then so are the eigenvalues of any nearby matrix (if you deform a bit the coefficients of a real polynomial with all roots real and distinct then the deformed polynomial has the same property, say by the implicit function theorem). So the answer is no.

Comment: @user8268 Why don't you flesh that out to an answer!! It is so much simpler than my argument. Not needing an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors and all that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the eigenvalues are distinct, then nearby matrices must also have $n$ distinct real eigenvalues as observed by user8268 in the comments.

On the other hand, if the eigenvalues of $A$ are not distinct, then there can be a complex conjugate pair of eigenvalues near $A$.  For example,
$$
\lVert I_{2\times 2}-R_\theta\rVert = \left\lVert\begin{pmatrix}
1-\cos\theta & \sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta & 1-\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\right\rVert
$$
which is $\approx C\lvert\theta\rvert$ for $\lvert\theta\rvert$ small.
So you can afford to get up to $m$ complex conjugate pairs, where $m=\sum_\lambda\left\lfloor\frac12\operatorname{mult}_\lambda(A)\right\rfloor$ and not any further.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Could you provide an argument for the second part? In particular, does the result depend on the diagonalizability of $A$? Does it still hold if $A$ is not diagolizable? Thanks.